# Malaysian passport name problems regarding first and last name

Tags: passports, malaysian-citizens

I had a question regarding how to put the first and last names for passports that don't have separate spaces for the two. Specifically Malaysian passports in this case.

What I mean is that for many passports like those of the US, you have a separate space for first name and last name, but for Malaysia you only have one long line that says "Name."

This wouldn't be a problem normally, but in my case the passport's name is "[English first name] [last name] [Chinese first name]" all in one line, and so I've been having problems because if I only put, for example, "Michael" and "Tan" in the first and last names, then I have my Chinese name remaining and it's not really my middle name either.

What should one do in these situations? Should I just stick to the first and last name?

Comment: Where exactly are you trying to put this information?

Comment: When I try to book the flight tickets. All of the websites, including official airline websites, require you to put the first and last name separately. I'm not sure how to put my name though, which is causing confusion. As I explained in the question, Malaysian passports don't have separate lines and often the surname is actually not at the end as would be normally thought of.

Comment: Hmm. I did some reading about it. It seems names in Malaysia can be really complicated as there are many cultures there, all with different conventions, and people may not even have surnames as Westerners think of them. I'd check the machine-readable section of the data page for what appears after `P<MYS`. All your names should appear with `<` between each of them. AFAIK most travel situations expect only the first two (if there even are as many as two) to be used. The interesting bit is that countries with surnames list the surname first, but it appears Malaysia does not necessarily do so.

Comment: But reversed names are common enough so nobody cares about that. If it were me I'd just use the first two names in the data line.

Comment: Ah I see, thanks for the insight. Right now the way that my name is written is "Michael Tan Ying Qin," and the first two are the ones I usually use with the latter two words being my Chinese given name. As you suggested, I checked my passport and it says `P<MYS<MICHAEL<TAN<YING<QIN`, so would that mean I should write Michael as my first name and only Tan as my last?

Comment: Ah, btw on the US visa that was issued, Michael is my first name and Tan is my last with no other name. I should probably follow that convention, right? I'm just asking because it's quite a common for Malaysians (especially Chinese) to spend long amounts of time convincing people that their last name is in the middle of their name...

Comment: While I was looking around I saw Malaysian passports with even more names than that! Anyway, yes, the computers will generally expect the first two names from the data line and ignore the rest, and usually they don't care about which order they're in as so many countries reverse the order of their names compared to Western countries where most of these computer systems were originally developed. Humans are generally easier to work with than computers, but it sounds like you are having the opposite problem...

Comment: Ah, apologies I meant to say that "Michael Ying Qin" is the first name and "Tan" is the last. I got confused with another visa. But yes, it doesn't seem like it should be a problem.

Comment: @Michael Hampton Your comments add up to a really great answer :-)

Comment: @Seankala According to the machine-readable passport standard, it should be `P<XXX<LASTNAME<<FIRST<MIDDLE<NAME`, with `<<` used to separate the last name and other names.

Comment: @dbkk Malaysian names don't work that way: OP's name is (English first name) (Last name) (Chinese first names), and for many the English name is just a nickname of sorts not listed on birth certs etc.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, I read up on this a lot as I have a Bruneian passport with the same issue. Your name should be written "Michael Tan Ying Qin" in last name, and if possible, you should indicate your passport has no first name. The first identifier in an MRZ is last name. Brunei and Malaysia don't differentiate because of the different cultures (even though Singapore is able to, go figure).